# get text, and split it after a given string

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there any javascript method to get text, and split it after a certain value?

Like for instance, having:

```
<p>here is some text <!-- read more --> and here is some more</p>
```

get this:

```
<p>here is some text</p> <p>and here is some more</p>
```

I suppose jQuery don't have the tools to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript and jQuery can absolutely achieve this. Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Brdk2/

Here's the code:

```
var p = $('p');
var textArray = p.html().split(' <!-- read more --> ');
p.replaceWith('<p>' + textArray.join('</p><p>') + '</p>');​
```

The `.split()` and `.join()` methods above are native JS. All other methods are jQuery. Let me know what questions you have.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example that does what you wish: http://jsfiddle.net/MsFVS/
this is the code:

```
var str="<p>here is some text <!-- read more --> and here is some more</p>";
str = str.replace("<!-- read more ", "</p>");
str = str.replace("-->", "<p>")
document.write("Our new str:"+str);
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Learn to love the `.split()` method. It's often a far better alternative to `.replace()`.

Comment: Yep... but in this simple case - there is no real need :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var string =my name is zeewon.this is me.
arr=[];
arr=string.split(".");
now you can manipulate the arraay arr which contains arr[0] and arr[1]
```